# How to consume Salesforce Change data Capture event using .net client

Tags: c#, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, change-data-capture

I am a .net developer and new to Salesforce. I have been asked to consume Change data capture events on certain tables. Salesforce admin have enabled the Change data capture event on Salesforce side.

Now how do I proceed with next steps. I know salesforce would publish events to a service bus. How do I subscribe to the service bus (find out address of service bus and credentials to connect).

I looked around but unable to find any .net based solution\client.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Find a library for capturing cometd / bayeux protocol messages.

Figure out a way to login to Salesforce (obtain session id, sometimes called "access token" especially if using REST API). Perhaps https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET. If you're adventurous - implement the login call yourself, it's just 1 SOAP / REST API request and there are some code samples: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm, https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5

Send a subscribe message to the right CDC channel. It'll probably be `/data/AccountChangeEvent`, `/data/CustomObject__ChangeEvent`. There's a training module for it: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/subscribe-to-events and it describes sample application (sadly - Java) you can try to follow the source code at least?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn’t have much .Net documentation. Pain because I’m not too fond of Java. However, did find a Git Repo, utilizing Java, to pick up CDC events on the tables that were enabled within our salesforce org. We set it up to pick up events in real time, and perform a call to a .Net service that parsed out the JSON and performed the same event to our On Prem DB.

Unfortunately, the listener does not pick up events from compound fields (EX: Name, Mailing address). Also, it does not pick up automated rules/triggers set on objects in salesforce (Ex: When Contact Status field is updated as “Invalid”, SecurityEndDate is set to todays date. The listener would only pick up the Contact Status field and not the SecurityEndDate)

Still have not had luck keeping on prem data in sync within real time, due to these issues. Good luck!